# CodeDom provider can't be located after another application deployed

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, roslyn, aspnet-compiler

I had two web applications deployed in a site under IIS 7.5

> site.com/myApp
>   site.com/anotherMyApp

Now another devs deployed their app as root application

> site.com/

Now when I access `site.com/myApp` or `/anotherMyApp` it throws:

> The CodeDom provider type
>   "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider,
>   Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" could not be
>   located.

Source error :

```
Line 54:   <system.codedom>
Line 55:     <compilers>
Line 56:       <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
Line 57:       <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
Line 58:     </compilers>
```

> Source File: C:\inetpub\wwwrootprettysite\THEIR APPLICATION\web.config

### Questions

**Why is this happening?

Why is the "source error" in *their application's webconfig* and how does it affect my application?

How do I fix my applications without breaking theirs?**

To clarify :

- Application hierarchy is correct, their application should be
  installed in root.
- .NET framework installed is 4.5.2
- Their application is using Roslyn compiler which is supplied in bin/roslyn
- My applications web.configs have no `<system.codedom>` section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your app inherits the config from its parent app, and your app doesn't have Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform. That's why you see that error. There are several options.

1. Override system.codedom setting in your web.config
2. Install Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform nupkg in your app

Comment: How do you exactly "override" system.codedom setting ?

Comment: Just add <system.codedom> into the web.config under your web app folder. If you just want to use old codedom provider, you can add the following setting.    <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
            <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v4.0" />
                <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false" />
            </compiler>            
//....